# Solve $x''-(\tan t)x'+2x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $x''-(\tan t)x'+2x=0$ knowing that $x=\sin t$ is one of the solutions

I really have no clue how to do this one. The fact that one of the solutions is given makes it look a bit similiar to Riccati's equation, but I dont think thats the right track.

Comment: Hint: change variable to $\tau = \sin t$, you can convert your ODE to [Legendre differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDifferentialEquation.html) for $\ell = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Reduction of order.  If $x(t) = u(t) \sin(t)$, and $v(t) = u'(t)$, you get a first-order linear differential equation for $v(t)$.

Comment: Why is it $x(t)=u(t)sin(t)$? Why not $x(t)=u(t)+sin(t)$?

Comment: @Lugi The sum or difference of solutions of a homogeneous linear equation is a solution, so $x(t) = u(t) + \sin(t)$ would just give you the original equation back.

Comment: @AndrewD No, it's reduction of order.  Variation of parameters is something different: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters

Comment: @RobertIsrael So it is.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=(\sin t)u$ ,

Then $x'=(\sin t)u'+(\cos t)u$

$x''=(\sin t)u''+(\cos t)u'+(\cos t)u'-(\sin t)u=(\sin t)u''+2(\cos t)u'-(\sin t)u$

$\therefore(\sin t)u''+2(\cos t)u'-(\sin t)u-(\tan t)((\sin t)u'+(\cos t)u)+2(\sin t)u=0$

$(\sin t)u''+2(\cos t)u'-(\sin t)u-\dfrac{\sin^2t}{\cos t}u'-(\sin t)u+2(\sin t)u=0$

$(\sin t)u''+\left(2\cos t-\dfrac{\sin^2t}{\cos t}\right)u'=0$

$(\sin t)u''=\left(\dfrac{\sin^2t}{\cos t}-2\cos t\right)u'$

$\dfrac{u''}{u'}=\tan t-2\cot t$

$\ln u'=-2\ln\sin t-\ln\cos t+c$

$u'=\dfrac{C_1}{\sin^2t\cos t}$

$u=C_1(\tanh^{-1}\sin t-\csc t)+C_2$

$\therefore x=C_1(\sin t\tanh^{-1}\sin t-1)+C_2\sin t$